# How to prevent showing blank notifications in cordova js

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, mobile

I'm using IONIC Framework for creating my mobile application.
I've created local notifications which fire at each minute. It sends an ajax request gets the response and creates the notification. But Sometimes the response is empty. which means that I don't need to show any kind of notification. I would like to know how can i prevent showing the notification in this case

```
 cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule(
            { 
              id: Date.now(),

              title: getText().text,

              every:'minute'            

           }

          );
```